# How to Send an Email from client side JS using my backend

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, wcf

I have class method for sending Email

```
public static bool SendEmail(string msg)
    {
        var sent = false;
        try
        {
            var fromEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"];
            var toEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ToEmail"];
            var emailsubject=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorTitle"];

            var emailService = new EmailServiceClient();
            sent = emailService.SendEmail(fromEmail, toEmail, emailsubject, msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
        return sent;
    }
```

Here is my Javascript function on on button Click() event

```
             function sendMail() {
       var e= "Hi";

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/SendEmail',
            method: "POST",  

        success:function (result) {
            alert('Email Sent');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Email Does Not Sent');
        }
        });

    }
```

This JS code is opening an outlook email of my system (open my mail client). 
I want to send the email on button click from my webpage directly via EmailService (not by SMTP because I have WCF created for EmailService), I am not understanding flow that how can I achieve it.

Need to know changes in JS code and Any documentation or example for reference would be helpful.
Thank You

Comment: You can only do that on your server.  Use AJAX.

Comment: Can you please give a code example, any other reference.

Comment: your question instantly becomes offtopic if you ask for code examples or a reference

Comment: @RuchiTang: What don't you understand? Did you try Googling AJAX?

Comment: I made the AJAX call but controller is not getting executed.

Comment: Do notice that `SendEmail` **can't** be a static method. Controller actions must be instance methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to read about [jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) and how to use the [jquery ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) , the code below is a good point to start, you did not mention if you are using MVC or API or WebForms, so code below is a bit generic. ([this is a complete guide that you can follow](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-API-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx))

```
function SendMail(){
var msg = 'your msg';

$.ajax({
                url: 'YOURURLHERE/SendEmail?msg=' + msg,
                method: "GET",               
            }).done(function (result) {
                alert('Email Sent');
                });
            });
}
```

Comment: Method GET or POST?

Comment: @RuchiTang in this case you can use GET or POST, I would use POST but if you want to be sure you can read this resource http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: Hi Victor, Your answer seems to be working for me, I edited my JS code according to your answer  but if I put the breakpoint to my HomeController method, the Call DOES NOT get executed. it directly throwing error function (alert).

Comment: Please see the C# code of controller method (public static bool SendEmail(string msg))

Comment: I also tried URL : url: 'Home/SendEmail?msg=' + msg
But not working

Comment: @RuchiTang if the answer is correct please mark it as correct, in case you need further information you can open a new question showing details of your error

Answer (score 1):

It worked with this:

```
 public ActionResult SendEmail(string msg)
    {
        var sent = false;
        try
        {

            var emailClient = new EmailServiceReference.EmailServiceClient();
            sent = emailClient.SendEmail(fromEmail, toEmail, emailsubject, msg);  /// All parameters of SendEmail method defined

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occured while sending Email " + ex.Message);
        }
        return Json(sent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```